# Can we reopen a question closed by a moderator?

Tags: support, closed-questions, vote-to-reopen

The question [Can I use a .NET 4 feature while targeting .NET 3.5 SP1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6119614/can-i-use-a-net-4-feature-while-targeting-net-3-5-sp1) has been closed as a dup by Jeff Atwood. Unfortunately, it's quite obviously not a dup of the "possible duplicate", [Conditional Compilation and Framework Targets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923210/c-conditional-compilation-and-framework-targets).

The question that was closed is asking about runtime behavior, while the possible duplicate is about compile-time behavior, which is completely unrelated.

I've flagged it and voted to reopen, but I'm not sure that either method I've tried will help since Jeff closed it. Can the question please be re-opened?

I ask because I have an actual answer to the question (as opposed to the current answers which are all wrong).

Comment: Are you questioning the discernment of the Stack Overflow deity? How dare you! (+1 for your audacity)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general any time I close any typical, regular question on Stack Overflow it is *not* sacred!*

We get a lot of close flags and I tend to follow the "we have so many dupes, it's probably a correct flag" rationale.

I am not in any way attached to the close, so handle it as you see fit.

<sub>meta on the other hand, I might get a little annoyed</sub>

<sub>* I guess there is an exception for some of the old subjective stuff from 2008 but I tend to delete that now more often than not</sub>

Comment: so if any guy ask for reopen, it will be reopened again?

Comment: Thanks. I just wanted to make sure!

Comment: @Damodar: You can flag it again for another moderator to review, or if it gets enough community votes to reopen we'll usually leave it open.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can. As long as he didn't lock it too its just closed; the same as if any other moderator or a group of 3k+ users had closed it.

That said, you probably want to be sure you are right or he'll just close it again *and* lock it. So convincing Jeff is probably an important step in there somewhere.

Comment: If you look at my answer, hopefully you'll agree that I'm right. :)

Comment: @Gabe: At the time you posted that comment, it had already been reopened. So, congratulations on verification by experiment ;)